# ArrayList does not fill in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a variable "ekinismi". And when I add String(s) to it. I receive the "eklist" from another activities with EkinIsmi() method.

```
static List<String> eklist = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> EkinIsmi() 
    {
        return eklist;
    }
```

But this list return me "null" and my list items. But I just want to receive only list items. How can I do that with a for loop or something. Null(s) are not String so I can't use equals or compareto for split the null(s) from my list.

This code sample is working good for me, but as you see, I give the list items number to the "i". But it has to understand what the list has.

```
if(ekinismi.size() > 1)
            {
                for(int i=ekinismi.size()-1; i>ekinismi.size()-3; i--)
                dosyaAdi.setText(String.valueOf(ekinismi.get(i)));
            }
```

[image]

I click the position = 0 list item and then click the next one and at the `dosyaAdi.setText()` is set first and next one's "s" . I mean I need to clear all the list items. Because it holds the first one's. Where should I put the `list.clear()`? Actually, I already do that but it didn't change anything, I think maybe I put it to wrong line.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if( ekvarmı == true)
        {
            if(ekinismi.size() >= 1)
            {
                for(String s : ekinismi) 
                    {
                       if(s != null) 
                       {
                           list.add(s);
                       }
                    }
                 dosyaAdi.setText(String.valueOf(list));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(String s : ekilist) {
   if(s != null) {
       doSomething(s);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yoru reply is solved my problem but I have actually another problem now. I edit it to under my question. I hope you can look at it..